# Edittext gains focus on activity stop

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code piece:

```
inputView?.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
        if (requireAuth()) {
          // inputView?.clearFocus()
        }
    }
}
```

`inputView` is an `EditText`. What I notice is, when activity finishes, `inputView` gains a focus. What is going on here? What would be the reason for it?

I might need to add a check `isFinishing` there as a workaround. I just want to know what is the logic behind and if I am doing something wrong.

---

**Edit**: It might be related; There is only one editText on the page, and there are several buttons.

Comment: onFocusChangeListener() is called upon the focus state of a view changed. means this will call when the hasFocus become false or two. When the activity is finished the foucs of edittext will be changed.

Comment: @SarithaG that is exactly my question. Why/how an edittext **gains** focus on activity finish?

Comment: Focus is gone, its not gaining..check hasFocus flag.

Comment: @SarithaG hasFocus = true

Answer (score 0):

to avoid auto focusing of any view you can set `android:focusable="true"` attribute of parent ViewGroup of that particular layout of yours, that maybe `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`

Comment: this is a good workaround when you face auto-focus problem on activity launch. however in my case (tho your offer might work as well), it is on activity destruction stage.